# BASH: insert a character each N positions of a string

Tags: bash

i have a string like this:

```
2015-09-24 12:05:00 2015-09-24 12:10:00 2015-09-24 12:15:00 2015-09-24 12:20:00
```

I would like to insert each 20 characters (except for the last one) a comma in order to have:

```
2015-09-24 12:05:00, 2015-09-24 12:10:00, 2015-09-24 12:15:00, 2015-09-24 12:20:00
```

How can i do?

Comment: Each 20 characters or after every date string (which *happens* to be 20 characters)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's define your string:

```
$ dates='2015-09-24 12:05:00 2015-09-24 12:10:00 2015-09-24 12:15:00 2015-09-24 12:20:00'
```

#### Insert every 20 characters

Now, let's insert a comma every 20 characters:

```
$ echo "$dates" | sed -r 's/.{20}/&,/g'
2015-09-24 12:05:00 ,2015-09-24 12:10:00 ,2015-09-24 12:15:00 ,2015-09-24 12:20:00
```

The commas are not quite where you want because the first date does not start with a space.  So, we can workaround that (GNU sed):

```
$ echo "$dates" | sed -r 's/^/ /; s/.{20}/&,/g; s/^ //'
2015-09-24 12:05:00, 2015-09-24 12:10:00, 2015-09-24 12:15:00, 2015-09-24 12:20:00,
```

#### Insert after every date

In GNU sed form:

```
$ echo "$dates" | sed -r 's/([^ ]* [^ ]*) /\1, /g'
2015-09-24 12:05:00, 2015-09-24 12:10:00, 2015-09-24 12:15:00, 2015-09-24 12:20:00
```